# 2006 Chevy Equinox doesn't have heat

Tags: chevrolet, heat, thermostat, equinox

Replaced the door that is in the dash and the thermostat. Still doesn't have heat. Very frustrated, this car hauls my grandkids around and the money invested is over $2000. We don't think the mechanic knows what the problem is and keeps trying things. Anyone have suggestion? My husband knows quite a bit about cars and it doesn't appear to be the heater core. They also checked and added coolant without issues

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: We're going to need quite a bit more information, including background on the problem and steps taken to resolve it. When you say the "door that is in the dash," are you referring to the blend door? Similarly, the thermostat is usually what regulates coolant flow to the engine block. Is that what was replaced? Do you notice low coolant temp (on the temp gauge)? Do you have problems with the AC?

Comment: Sorry, I am not the smartest with this stuff. She started noticing this in the Spring but didn't think anything of it because it wasn't too cold out. Yes, the blend door was replaced. .I think the mechanic looked online for common issues with this year and came to the resolution of the blend door. Air is coming out but it is cool air. The thermostat was also replaced. There is no low coolant temp that I have heard about. haven't heard that there is problems with the AC.

Comment: It ended up being a loose clamp on a hose

Comment: Assuming you have a good blend door and the actuator is not broken, which they like to do,
The upper heater hose has a T and there is a restrictor in it. Its plastic. Drill it out to 1/4" and that should help get rid of the air lock in the heater core